# NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED error in Firefox using Dojo

Tags: javascript, firefox, dojo, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a strange issue that's being thrown in Firefox when using my Dojo (v.1.10.0) application.

Here is the following error that I'm seeing in Firefox:

```
Exception 
    { message: "",
      result: 2147549183, 
      name: "NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED", 
      filename: "http://localhost:8888/dojo/on.js", 
      lineNumber: 354, 
      columnNumber: 0, 
      inner: null, 
      data: null 
    } 
  ""
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to go with this in my application. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

On line 354 of dojo/on, this is happening:

```
 if(has("dom-addeventlistener")){
    // emitter that works with native event handling
    on.emit = function(target, type, event){
        if(target.dispatchEvent && document.createEvent){
            // use the native event emitting mechanism if it is available on the target object
            // create a generic event               
            // we could create branch into the different types of event constructors, but 
            // that would be a lot of extra code, with little benefit that I can see, seems 
            // best to use the generic constructor and copy properties over, making it 
            // easy to have events look like the ones created with specific initializers
            var ownerDocument = target.ownerDocument || document;
            var nativeEvent = ownerDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            nativeEvent.initEvent(type, !!event.bubbles, !!event.cancelable);
            // and copy all our properties over
            for(var i in event){
                if(!(i in nativeEvent)){
                    nativeEvent[i] = event[i];
                }
            }
            return target.dispatchEvent(nativeEvent) && nativeEvent; // Line 354
        }
        return syntheticDispatch.apply(on, arguments); // emit for a non-node
    };
}
```

Comment: Just added to the comments. Thank you for the feedback @admdrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a generic FF error message... it's usually triggered by a timing or race condition, which may explain why it's showing up via dojo/on. Maybe the target or event handler that you're trying to work with is acting on something that has been removed, etc. It's unclear without knowing what event is triggering it or without seeing your full code example.

For example, maybe you're trying to add event listeners before the DOM is available, but that's just a guess. Or maybe the target node doesn't exist.

You can use the debugger to see the values of the event parameters, or you can look at your various event registration mechanisms, etc.

Comment: thank you for the response (and the lead). I'll try to dig deeper into any / all events. Such as a strange error! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar issue using intern 2.0 and unit tests creating native select boxes.

Some library code (verified that its not our own) triggers a dojo.emit() which causes the internal error.

We're trying to identify the problem in more detail. If you find something please let us know as well!

Comment: My issue was exactly what @Dylan said -- I had an extra element in my template I forgot to include via AMD

Answer (score 0):

we were also getting same exception at exactly same point,

for us, we replaced our code 
`elementReference.destroy() // destroy is a dojo function` with `elementReference.domNode.remove()` and it solved our problem.